# How to edit and see live CSS effect in IE8 like we see in Firefox > Web developer toolbar > Edit CSS function?

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8, web-developer-toolbar

How to edit and see css effect in IE8 like we see in Firefox > Web developer toolbar > Edit CSS function?

Where is similar function in IE8 developer toolbar or does any other IE plugin have this  type functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN, this is doable directly with the IE8 developer tools:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx#html_liveedit

Comment: OK, I'm not 100% sure how WDT does it, but if you open up IE8 Dev Toolbar and go to the CSS tab, you can edit any style, and right-click on a selector to add new attributes, or add new rules before/after the one you clicked on. You can also check/uncheck boxes to temporarily disable rules. What else does WDT do that this can't achieve?

Comment: Live CSS editing only works in some cases, for example it doesn't work when there are certain AJAX elements in the page

Answer (score -1):

Ok, but this still doesn't allow you to directly edit CSS in an editor. Instead, you are required to right click -> add each time you want to add a line to the css. If you are adding more than 1 item to the css, the tool is basically useless.

Its also not obvious how to directly edit comments, etc.

The html editor, however, does contain a full editor which allows you to directly edit the html.

You could try firebug, or firebug light if you don't have admin access to your pc. Its not exactly the solution either though.

Hopefully you have access to firefox and developer toolbar. Then you can write compliant code, then backport the code to IE8. But some IE8 specific css hacks are broken in the IE8 developer bar, so if your using hacks to get it to look right, be prepared for that.